# How to treat stdin like a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

I have a program that reads parses a text file and does some analysis on it. I want to modify it so it can take parameters via the command line. Reading from the file when it is designated stdin.

The parser looks like this:

```
class FastAreader :
    '''
    Class to provide reading of a file containing one or more FASTA
    formatted sequences:
    object instantiation:
    FastAreader(<file name>):

    object attributes:
    fname: the initial file name

    methods:
    readFasta() : returns header and sequence as strings.
    Author: David Bernick
    Date: April 19, 2013
    '''
    def __init__ (self, fname):
        '''contructor: saves attribute fname '''
        self.fname = fname

    def readFasta (self):
        '''
        using filename given in init, returns each included FastA record
        as 2 strings - header and sequence.
        whitespace is removed, no adjustment is made to sequence contents.
        The initial '>' is removed from the header.
        '''
        header = ''
        sequence = ''

        with open(self.fname) as fileH:
            # initialize return containers
            header = ''
            sequence = ''

            # skip to first fasta header
            line = fileH.readline()
            while not line.startswith('>') :
                line = fileH.readline()
            header = line[1:].rstrip()

            # header is saved, get the rest of the sequence
            # up until the next header is found
            # then yield the results and wait for the next call.
            # next call will resume at the yield point
            # which is where we have the next header
            for line in fileH:
                if line.startswith ('>'):
                    yield header,sequence
                    header = line[1:].rstrip()
                    sequence = ''
                else :
                    sequence += ''.join(line.rstrip().split()).upper()
        # final header and sequence will be seen with an end of file
        # with clause will terminate, so we do the final yield of the data
        yield header,sequence

# presumed object instantiation and example usage
# myReader = FastAreader ('testTiny.fa');
# for head, seq in myReader.readFasta() :
#     print (head,seq)
```

It parses files that look like this:

```
>test
ATGAAATAG
>test2
AATGATGTAA
>test3
AAATGATGTAA

>test-1
TTA CAT CAT

>test-2
TTA CAT CAT A

>test-3
TTA CAT CAT AA

>test1A
ATGATGTAAA
>test2A
AATGATGTAAA
>test3A
AAATGATGTAAA

>test-1A
A TTA CAT CAT

>test-2A
AA TTA CAT CAT A

>test-3A
AA TTA CAT CAT AA
```

My test program looks like this:

```
import argparse
import sequenceAnalysis as s
import sys

class Test:
    def __init__(self, infile, longest, min, start):
        self.longest = longest
        self.start = set(start)
        self.infile = infile
        self.data = sys.stdin.read()
        self.fasta = s.FastAreader(self.data)
        for head, seq in self.fasta.readFasta():
            self.head = head
            self.seq = "".join(seq).strip()
        self.test()

    def test(self):
        print("YUP", self.start, self.head)


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Program prolog', 
                                     epilog = 'Program epilog', 
                                     add_help = True, #default is True 
                                     prefix_chars = '-', 
                                     usage = '%(prog)s [options] -option1[default] <input >output')
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--inFile', action = 'store', help='input file name')
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--outFile', action = 'store', help='output file name') 
    parser.add_argument('-lG', '--longestGene', action = 'store', nargs='?', const=True, default=True, help='longest Gene in an ORF')
    parser.add_argument('-mG', '--minGene', type=int, choices= range(0, 2000), action = 'store', help='minimum Gene length')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--start', action = 'append', nargs='?', help='start Codon') #allows multiple list options
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 0.1')  
    args = parser.parse_args()
    test = Test(args.inFile, args.longestGene, args.minGene, args.start)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My commandline input looks like this:

```
python testcommand2.py -s ATG <tass2.fa >out.txt
```

Where tass2.fa is a filewhich can be parsed by FastAreader. I can pass paramters like start and get them to output to the text file but when I try to parse the input file which should be stdin it prints everything instead of parsing it and instead of outputting to the designated textfile which should be stdout it prints it directly to the commandline.

Comment: Is your command line something like: `python test.py < in.txt > parsed.txt` ? Can you show the command line you use (per [ask]) ?

Comment: @boardrider Sorry, my post has been edited accordingly. But yes that is what my command input looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use I/O redirection (i.e. you have `<` or `|` or `>` or `<<` in the command line), that is handled by the shell even before your program runs. So when Python runs, its standard input is connected to the file or pipe you are redirecting from, and its standard output is connected to the file or pipe you are redirecting to, and the file names are not (directly) visible to Python because you are dealing with already `open()`ed file handles, not file names. Your argument parser simply returns nothing, because there are no file name arguments.

To correctly cope with this, you should adapt your code to work with file handles directly -- instead of, or in addition to, explicit file names.

For the latter scenario, a common convention is to have a special case for the file name `-` and when that is passed in, use standard input (or standard output, depending on context)  instead of  opening a file. (You can still have files named like that by the  simple  workaround of using a relative path `./-` so the name is not exactly a single dash.)