# How to read "-" (dash) as standard input with Python without writing extra code?

Tags: python, stdin, contextmanager

Using Python 3.5.x, not any greater version than that.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30254551/257924 is the right answer, but doesn't provide a solution that is built into Python, but requires writing code from scratch:

I need to have a string that has a value of "-" to represent stdin, or its value is a path to a text file I want to read from.  I want to use the `with` operator to open up either type of those files, without using conditional logic to check for "-" in my scripts. I have something that works, but it seems like it should be something that is built into Python core and not requiring me to roll my own context-manager, like this:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def read_text_file_or_stdin(path):
    """Return a file object from stdin if path is '-', else read from path as a text file."""
    if path == '-':
        with open(0) as f:
            yield f
    else:
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            yield f


# path = '-'  # Means read from stdin
path = '/tmp/paths'  # Means read from a text file given by this value
with read_text_file_or_stdin(path) as g:
    paths = [path for path in g.read().split('\n') if path]

print("paths", paths)
```

I plan to pass in the argument to a script via something like `-p -` to mean "read from standard-input" or `-p some_text_file` meaning "read from some_text_file".

Does this require me to do the above, or is there something built into Python 3.5.x that provides this already? This seems like such a common need for writing CLI utilities, that it could have already been handled by something in the Python core or standard libraries.

I don't want to install any module/package from repositories outside of the Python standard library in 3.5.x, just for this.

Comment: @baao `-` is a standard convention for specifying standard input where a filename is otherwise expected.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you may be interested in the [`fileinput` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/fileinput.html).

Comment: You can simply `yield sys.stdin` if standard input is requested; there's no need to create a new file handle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `argparse` module provides a `FileType` factory which knows about the `-` convention.

```
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()

p.add_argument("-p", type=argparse.FileType("r"))

args = p.parse_args()
```

Note that `args.p` is an open file handle, so there's no need to open it "again". While you can still use it with a `with` statement:

```
with args.p:
    for line in args.p:
        ...
```

this only ensures the file is closed in the event of an error in the `with` statement itself. Also, you may not want to use `with`, as this will close the file, even if you meant to use it again later.

You should probably use the `atexit` module to make sure the file gets closed by the end of the program, since it was already opened for you at the beginning.

```
import atexit

...

args = p.parse_args()
atexit.register(args.p.close)
```

Comment: For: "Also, you may not want to use with, as this will close the file, even if you meant to use it again later." : thanks for that caution. In this case, I actually do want to read either from stdin or the real file only once, so I'm going to actually use `with` here.

Comment: For optional context manager it is better to use `with contextlib.ExitStack() as file_stack:` ... then inside the context optionally execute: `file_stack.enter_context(args.p)` See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack ------ But anyway `argparse.FileType()` is not well suited for use with context managers as the file gets opened before defining any context.

Comment: Yeah, I've never really used `FileType` much myself. It's probably most suitable for quick, simple scripts where it doesn't matter much if you don't close the file explicitly. But as such scripts tend to evolve into longer, more complex scripts, taking a file name and opening it yourself with a context manager is probably preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Check https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects.

Where you can do like this

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
...                     default=sys.stdin)
>>> parser.add_argument('outfile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('w'),
...                     default=sys.stdout)
```

So `infile` & `outfile` will support read & write streams for `stdin` & `stdout` by default.

### Or using my favorite library `click`

Check more details at the library docs website

https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.File
https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/arguments/#file-arguments

> **File Arguments**
>
> Since all the examples have already worked with filenames, it makes sense to explain how to deal with files properly. Command line tools are more fun if they work with files the Unix way, which is to accept `-` as a special file that refers to stdin/stdout.
>
> Click supports this through the click.File type which intelligently handles files for you. It also deals with Unicode and bytes correctly for all versions of Python so your script stays very portable.

The library is the most "BASH/DASH" features friendly I believe.

Comment: +1. I had stumbled upon `type=argparse.FileType('r')` in the help page at https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs ,  but was tripped up by the nargs reference. Had I dug deeper I would have seen the https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects page you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks also for the reference to the https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.File `click` library that might have been an option if it wasn't for the constraint I put in as the last paragraph of the OP of: "I don't want to install any module/package from repositories outside of the Python standard library in 3.5.x, just for this."  Hence why I'm marking https://stackoverflow.com/a/59381303/257924 as the answer. But really yours and the other answer are otherwise equivalent.